# OOP PHP Random string for instance name error

Tags: php, laravel

In short, I have an image class that when a new instance is made, it will receive a unique name (random string name).  But I am getting an error that is over my head since I am quite new to OOP.

Class

```
class Image extends Eloquent {
  public $name = Str::random(); // Built in Laravel Class
}
```

Test Route

```
Route::get('/test', function() {
    $test = new Image();
    return $test->name;
});
```

Returns Error

`syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'`

What should happen is that instance receives a unique name.  The code looks fine to me, am I not allowed to call static methods from other classes in a class?  Thank you for your time.

Comment: RTFM http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php#example-195

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with Laravel but try:

```
class Image extends Eloquent {
  public $name ;
  function __construct(){
      $this->name = Str::random(); // Built in Laravel Class
      parent::__construct();
  }
}
```